# executing an ssh command in php via exec -ssh key issue

Tags: php, ubuntu, ssh, php-7

I have a bit of code that runs on the remote server fine but will not run on my local php instance.

```
    private function serverCmd($server, $cmd, $exec = false) {
    $line = system("whoami");
    print($line."\n");
    $localCmd = 'ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no myuser@uk-staging.internal.myhost.com "mkdir -p /home/deploy/backups/etl; rm -f /home/deploy/backups/etl/*.gz; rm -f /home/deploy/backups/etl/*.csv; sudo chown myhost:mysql /home/deploy/backups/etl"';
    for ($retry = 0; $retry < 10; $retry++) {
        if ($exec) {
            $output = array();
            exec($localCmd, $output, $retval);
            if ($retval === 0) return $output;
        }
        else {
            system($localCmd, $retval)
            if ($retval === 0) return true;
        }
        sleep(1);
    }
    return false;
}
```

The issue is with the this line : system($localCmd, $retval).

if i run the ssh command directly on my ubuntu shell it works but if php trys to run it via that line it just hangs and I get the following error on the server its trying to ssh into :
sshd[10203]: Postponed keyboard-interactive for my user sshd[10202]: error: PAM: Authentication failure for myuser.

My dev machine has ssh keys setup to that I can just ssh in without entering a password. I assumed that php would use the same as its using my user.

How do I make sure php is using the same keys and authentication methods to ssh in as my shell? This is a cli script

Anybody got any ideas?

Comment: PHP might NOT be using your user, and is instead connecting as teh www-data user, which wouldn't have access to your private key.  You'll need to put your private key someplace the webserver can access it, change ownership/permissions as appropriate, and then in your `ssh` command use hte `-i` option to point to that particular private key to use as your identitity

Comment: @ivanivan its a cli script and if i do: system("whoami"); it shows that its using the same user.

Comment: totally at a loss with this